# Exception using QueryEngine inside a Transaction

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I'm using the neo4j 1.9.M01 version with the java-rest-binding 1.8.M07, and I have a problem with this code that aims to get a node from a neo4j database with the property "URL" that is "ARREL", using the Query language via rest. The problems seems to happens only inside a transaction, throwing an exception, but otherwise works well :

```
RestGraphDatabase graphDb = new RestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
RestCypherQueryEngine queryEngine = new RestCypherQueryEngine(graphDb.getRestAPI());
Node nodearrel = null;
Transaction tx0 = gds.beginTx();
try{
 final String queryStringarrel = ("START n=node(*) WHERE n.URL =~{URL} RETURN n");
 QueryResult<Map<String, Object>> retornar = queryEngine.query(queryStringarrel, MapUtil.map("URL","ARREL"));
 for (Map<String,Object> row : retornar) 
  {
   nodearrel = (Node)row.get("n");
   System.out.println("Arrel: "+nodearrel.getProperty("URL")+" id : "+nodearrel.getId());
  }
tx0.success();
}
(...)
```

But an exception happens: *exception tx0: Error reading as JSON ''
* every execution at the line that returns the QueryResult object.

I also have tried to do it with the ExecutionEngine (between a transaction):

```
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( graphDb );
String ARREL = "ARREL";
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("START n=node(*) WHERE n.URL =~{"+ARREL+"} RETURN n");
Iterator<Node> n_column = result.columnAs("n");
Node arrelat = (Node) n_column.next();
for ( Node node : IteratorUtil.asIterable( n_column ) )
(...)
```

But it also fails at the *n_column.next()* returning a null object that throws an exception.

The problem is that I need to use the transactions to optimize the queries due if not it take too much time processing all the queries that I need to do. Should I try to join several operations to the query, to avoid using the transactions?

Answer (score 0):

try to add single quotes at:

```
START n=node(*) WHERE n.URL =~ '{URL}' RETURN n
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the exception seems to persist.

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your java-rest-binding to the latest version (1.8) ? In between we had a version that automatically applied REST-batch-operations to places with transaction semantics.

So the transactions you see are not real transactions but just recording your operations to be executed as batch-rest-operations on `tx.success/finish`

Execute the queries within the transaction, but only access the results **after** the tx is finished. Then your results will be there.

This is for instance useful to send many cypher queries in one go to the server and have the results available all in one go afterwards.

And yes @ulkas use parameters but not like that:

```
START n=node(*) WHERE n.URL =~ {URL} RETURN n

params: { "URL" : "http://your.url" }
```

No quotes neccessary when using params, just like SQL prepared statements.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do your solution. Thanks alot for the answer.